# PTIJ: Future heter for tattoos?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It says in [Yirmiyahu 31:32](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1131.htm):

> "But this is the covenant that I will make with the house of Israel after those days, saith the LORD, **I will put My law in their inward parts, and in their heart will I write it**; and I will be their God, and they shall be My people."

In the future, Hashem will inscribe the new covenant in our hearts. Does this mean that in the future, tattoos will be kosher?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 0):

This specific type of tatoo on one's heart would pose some severe halachic restrictions, not to mention the health dangers involved with putting etchings on one's heart. I'll address the halachic problems, only, and you can contact your LHD (Local halachic doctor) for the medical aspect.

First of all the law is God's word, and, most likely, it would have God's name on it. As you know, one may not obliterate God's name.

That's fine. But what happens when the heart becomes thick? Then, one has to circumcise the thick covering (which may have God's name on it), as it says:

וּמַלְתֶּ֕ם אֵ֖ת עָרְלַ֣ת לְבַבְכֶ֑ם

(Devarim 10:16)

And, thus, he would be obliterating God's name.

My own feeling - At least heart tatoos probably would never be made kosher to prevent this problem from occuring. It sounds too halachically risky.

Comment: What about tattoos in general?

Comment: I have to admit - this isn't the greatest worded question, as you cited a verse that mentions specifically inscribing on the heart, and are trying to extend the idea to all areas of the body. I understand that with PTIJ, we have a lot of relaxed rules, but in terms of my answering in a way that's related to the main area of the question, I have only addressed that.

Comment: my understanding - which apparently isn't shared by all - was that as there's a heter, apparently, for one area, there's a heter for all.